# TensorFlow Memory always exceeds 10% system memory

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a `WALSModel` (see [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oJDfvIWnf7sY5uFcJ7XhTSEdA1n_3Jxv)) locally.

Regardless of the system on which I try to run, I always encounter allocation errors; namely that it exceeds 10% of system memory.

I have tried on a modest system with 8GB ram and `4GiB` on the GPU (says its needs `4.5GiB` to allocate). I then tried on a system with 16GB ram and `8GiB` on a 1070 GPU and it says it needs to allocate `9.1GiB` memory. I am now trying on a system with 100GiB ram and `16GiB` on the GPU, and it says it needs `17 GiB`.

The model will run on CPU despite the warning because it does not actually need this much (more on that in a moment). However when using a GPU it will throw an error killing the process.

What am I doing wrong? (see [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oJDfvIWnf7sY5uFcJ7XhTSEdA1n_3Jxv) for all code necessary to run).

The data, on disk, is less than `2GiB`. So I do not understand why it always says it needs at least 10% more than what is available. Especially as when running on the GPU it says it tried to allocate 4.5, 9.1 and 17 GiB, and then when I run on 8, 16, 100 GiB ram, I still get the warning that allocation exceeds more than 10% of system memory

#### Hardward Specs

CPU

```sh
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          95325       36405       30328         283       28591       57339
Swap:         96933         101       96832
```

GPU

```sh
name: Quadro GP100 major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.4425
pciBusID: 0000:af:00.0
totalMemory: 15.90GiB freeMemory: 14.75GiB
```

#### Data details

```py
shape = (210000, 44000)
```

```sh
# SciPy coordinate form file on disk
1.903 GiB
```

#### Log Details

Run on GPU

```sh
Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 17.32GiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
```

Run on CPU

```sh
W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:108] Allocation of 18599850000 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

Comment: Is it possible there's a memory leak? That looks to me like it's just consuming as much memory as possible until memory allocation creates an error - which can only happen once the requested amount is greater than that which is available, so it would _always_ appear to be somewhat above the available memory.

Comment: @Avery it is possible, but I doubt it. In the code you can see I am manually calling garbage collection to ensure that it doesnt and the code does run for smaller matrices without a problem (and printing out resources shows that it doesnt grow). So I think that this matrix is just large enough that maybe it triggers some bug during allocation.

Comment: Manually calling GC doesn't help if there are too many references being held - they will always appear to be active and not ready for GC. If you can run smaller data sets though, maybe you can try to calculate how the memory needs scale with data size and estimate what your usage "should" be?

Comment: @Avery, well in the code in the linked colab I have the SciPy `sp.sparse.coo_matrix`, the `tf.SparseTensor` and the `WALSModel`. Since the dense file is ~2GiB, and the `WALSModel` results in two smaller matrices `n x k` and `k x m`, where `k << n && k << m` I would hope that the upper bound on memory usage would be `6GiB`

Comment: @Avery in addition I call `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss` which on CPU returns `14386424`. To my understanding this is kilobytes on Linux systems. So this "max" model is `~14.4GiB` at _peak_ usage. So the Quadro with `freeMemory: 14.75GiB` should be enough...